# Riot, Stack Exchange, Reddit, Telegram, or all of the above?

Tags: discussion

I'm trying my best to stay up to date with all things Tezos, but channels seam to proliferate-- what is the prime channel you guys monitored to be up to date on Tezos (specifically baking details)?

Answer (score 7):

Below you can find some helpful resources to stay updated on everything happening in Tezos Protocol:

- t.me/TezosAnnouncements - Stay up to date with our announcements channel;
- reddit.com/r/tezos/- The main Tezos Reddit, excellent for getting fresh news;
- twitter.com/tezosfoundation - another good way to be updated with the latest news;
- twitter.com/ArthurB - Arthur Breitman;
- twitter.com/breitwoman - Kathleen Breitman;
- tezos.help and tezos.rocks - probably the most helpful website in terms of navigating through all Tezos related resources! These websites have information on everything starting from wallets and finishing with smartcontract coding;
- riot.im/app/#/room/%23tezos:matrix.org - Tezos Riot Community, this place is the main home to Tezos developers and other well known community members.
- t.me/tezosplatform - The largest Tezos Telegram Chat;
- t.me/Tezos_Baking - A friendly Telegram Baking Community;
- t.me/tezostrader - Tezos Trading Telegram Chat;

If you wish to join Baking Slack channel ask for invite by emailing tezos@obsidian.systems

Answer (score 2):

When you are mostly interested in baking, the Tezos baking channel on Slack from Obsidian Systems is probably the best resource (besides Tezos Stack Exchange of course ;-). You must request access though by sending an email to tezos@obsidian.systems.